# Highcharts zooming makes disappear data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I'm using React and the Highcharts library to create line charts, where all the data comes from the database. Now, for zooming, I'm using the mouse scroll. The issue arises when I zoom in with the scroll multiple times; at a certain point, all the data disappears, and the chart is no longer visible. I've checked the console, and no errors are appearing. I've tried setting "navigate" to true and noticed that if I choose a range of values that are more current, it doesn't display any data, but there's no issue with another range. Do you happen to know a possible solution? Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a complex chart!  Without a minimal reproducible example it would be impossible to guess at a solution that is anything more than extremely generic, like "check the code that runs when the user zooms in" and "use the debugging features of devtools to narrow down where in the code this problem occurs".

Comment: Hi @Azalea, Please reproduce your problem in some online code editor. You can use this example: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/highcharts-react-demo-gbg3n3 as a base to start.